# How to maximize browser using Sahi with java

Tags: java, browser, sahi

I'm using Sahi Java Driver. My Java code with Sahi is running well. When tests are being executed the browser (in my case Firefox) is not maximized. The snippet of my Sahi Java code as below:

```
String browserType = "firefox";
Browser browser = new Browser(browserType);
browser.open();
```

How can I maximize the browser in Sahi with Java?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Sahi Pro, you have a browserAction API which takes in maximize as a parameter. This will maximize your browser. It also takes other parameters such as focus, minimize, refresh etc. You can check that out. So your code can be something like this:

```
browser.windowAction('maximize') //please check the syntax, copy paste might go wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

The following line of Sahi Java code work fine. Add the following line of code after browser.open() ;

```
browser.focusWindow();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be like,

-Make a Java Script code for full screen

```
function maximize() {
window.moveTo(0, 0);
window.resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
}
maximize();
```

-Run this script before start the test 
browser.execute("ScriptToRun")

thanks

Comment: The above JS code looks fine. But, as there is a simple single line of code in Sahi with Java, why does it need to use several lines of JS code?

Comment: The above JS code looks good. I have implemented it in my code, but unfortunately the browser (FF) is not being maximized.